# Safely refresh activity details from AsyncTask

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-activity

I have an Android app with an associated website. 
I've a LoginActivity which accepts user credentials, uses an AsyncTask subclass to verify them with the website, and if correct stores them in SharedPreferences for future use.

I've a MainActivity which displays user details, based on those SharedPreferences values.

So when the AsyncTask completes, I need to refresh the user details displayed in the Main activity.

1. I could do this by passing a reference to the MainActivity to the LoginActivity when calling it, and then in the AsyncTask onPostExecute, call a function in that MainActivity instance to refresh the displayed data.
   This seems to be a common way of doing it, but I'm not sure if it's completely safe. It's unlikely, but what happens if the MainActivity is terminated by the OS while the AsyncTask is still processing?
2. Alternatively, in this instance I could just finish() the MainActivity when I start the LoginActivity, and launch a new MainActivity from the onPostExecute which would display the refreshed data.
   But I may have other activities where user interaction is proceeding while a background AsyncTask is refreshing data - in those cases the second method won't work.

Just wondering if there's a better way of doing it, or is the first way safe enough?

Comment: 1. To deal with MainActivity shutting down while the AsyncTask is processing you should have the MainActivity 'unregister' itslef with the AsyncTask, and then before the task makes a call back to the main activity it should check if the activity has 'unregistered' itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I could do this by passing a reference to the MainActivity to the LoginActivity when calling it, and then in the AsyncTask onPostExecute, call a function in that MainActivity instance to refresh the displayed data.

The out-of-the-box way of dealing with activities coming and going is to use [`AsyncTaskLoader`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/AsyncTaskLoader.html). This approach implements @ByteMe's suggestion to unregister/register activity instances. Unfortunately, its programmer API is... less than painless. In particular, the API is written for a screen that begins loading immediately when it's opened. Using the [Loaders](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/loaders.html) API in a screen that begins loading upon user interaction is perfectly possible, but the implementation is a bit awkward.

A common alternate approach –still using only core- and support-v4 library classes– is to use an [`IntentService`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/IntentService.html) to do the background work and the [`LocalBroadcastManager`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/content/LocalBroadcastManager.html) to deliver the result.

If using Open Source libraries is an option, you might want to look at [Otto Bus](http://square.github.io/otto/) or [RxJava](https://github.com/Netflix/RxJava) to deliver the "load finished" event.

> Alternatively, in this instance I could just finish() the MainActivity when I start the LoginActivity, and launch a new MainActivity from the onPostExecute which would display the refreshed data.

If I understand correctly, the `MainActivity` is your launch activity. The first thing it does is check if login is necessary and, if it is, it directs to `LoginActivity`. If login isn't necessary, it shows the account data and if it is, it waits for `LoginActivity` to return.

This sounds to me like a perfect fit for [`startActivityForResult(Intent, int)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29). Just have the main activity launch the login activity with a request code. The login activity can call [`setResult(int, Intent)`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult%28int,%20android.content.Intent%29) with a return code and the authentication data. The main activity can then implement [`onActivityResult()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29) to get the return value from the login activity and do all that needs to be done.

As an added benefit, you can centralise all `SharedPreferences` interaction in the main activity and keep it entirely outside login activity. This makes for lower coupling between the two.

An entirely different approach that you could consider is to ditch user authentication entirely and rely on [Google+ Sign-in](https://developers.google.com/+/) to identify users by their Google+ account. You can do the same through [Facebook](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#onActivityResult%28int,%20int,%20android.content.Intent%29). On the upside, using either of these (or both) will completely free you from the responsibility of managing authentication and credentials in a secure way. On the downside, there's vendor lock-in and it may scare off some users.

Comment: Great, startActivityForResult / onActivityResult is exactly what I need, works perfectly. I like the suggestion of passing back the data and centralising the SharedPrefs access, makes more sense. Thanks a million